# Python + SQL + XML: NoneType object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: sql, xml, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm trying to write a Python program that scans a particular [XML Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzHSKu-P4SYtaFNzSUQzUFhMRm8/view?usp=sharing)  for data and writes that data to tables in an SQLite database. My code is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Wk03_Assign01.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;

CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id INTEGER,
    title TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Track (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT UNIQUE,
    album_id INTEGER,
    genre_id INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, 
    rating INTEGER, 
    count INTEGER
);

''')


fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : 
    fname = 'Library.xml'

def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : 
        continue
    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')

    if name is None or artist is None or album is None : 
        continue

cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name) 
    VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (artist_id, title) 
    VALUES ( ?, ? )''', (artist_id, album  ) )
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) 
    VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
    (title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''', 
    ( name, album_id, genre_id, length, rating, count ) )

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

While the rest of my code is working perfectly fine, the segment:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) 
    VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

is causing the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Course 04\Wk03_Ass01.py", line 83, in <module>
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I'm utterly baffled as to why this is happening. The segment of code causing the traceback is identical (except for variable names) to the sections above it, which work perfectly. I thought the error might have been occurring because some entries in the 'Genre' database are NULL, but I put the cur.fetchone() statement in an if statement, which also did not work.

```
cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) 
    VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
sqlstr = 'SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, )
if cur.execute(sqlstr) is None:
    continue
else:
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

I'd really appreciate any insight into what is going wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a fix. Evidently the 'Genre' data was NULL at some points and that was screwing up the data. I fixed it using a conditional IF statement as follows:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) 
    VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', t)
genre_id_val = cur.fetchone()
if genre_id_val is None:
    continue
else:
    genre_id = genre_id_val[0]
```

The if/else statement worked!

Answer (score 0):

First check if there is something to fetch, and then fetch it...
`if cur.rowcount == 1:` is something you can use to validate if there is single row result. You can also use `fetchall()` and check the returned list. The difference is that if result is big - you will fetch it all, so `rowcount` is better option.

## EDIT

Try to pass exact string. If that works, problem is with the way you pass query to `execute`. According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3), which you for sure knows:

```
# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()
```

Comment: cur.fetchall() does return a long list of results, so the SQL INSERT and SELECT statements are definitely working as intended.

Comment: Doing `genre_id = cur.fetchone()` instead of `genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]` returns results, but then I get a different traceback instead.

I tried passing the query to Execute the way you suggested, but it didn't affect the results.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the bug! Thanks for your help though. :)